# JQuery .Load() passing a variable with a value after the ajax .load is complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

On click, I have a function that grabs the value of a radio button and stores it in a variable.

Next, this function fires off an ajax .load().

My issue is, the variable that holds the radio button's value is lost. How can I pass this variable with the value to another function?

Thanks.

code in the function:

```
var radio = $("input[name=selection]:checked").val();

$("#result").load(url, {var1 : val1},
       function() {
       $('form').fadeIn();
});
```

I would like to pass the value of the var radio to the form

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: The `radio` variable should still be in scope in the `.load()` callback.

Comment: you don't need to pass it, just use it.

Comment: I think it's not because the page is reloaded, thus losing the radio value. What im trying to achieve is to pass the radio and its value after the .load runs. I want to use this value in my form.

Comment: Hey sorry guys, im a fool, your right, it is there! thank you guys!